# Android ViewPager not updating next position

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager, in that trying to change sum values on current view, but not able to get reflect on next or previous view, since those views are already got ready before I change my current view.

For example I am in 3rd(position) view, once try to change some text and I want to reflect that in 2nd view or 4th view.

Once I clicked a view the count will be increased, as well as I want to reflect in both previous and next view when I move to previous or next position .

```
Here is my code:

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    int height, width;
    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_item_row, null);

        mArticleCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.articleCount);
        finalCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.finalCount);

        mArticleCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalCount.setText(getCount());
            });
            container.addView(v);
            return v;
        }
    }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mArticlesModel.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            MLog.i("destroy item", "@@@ pos = " + position);
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }
```